# In a member function of base class, what will `(Derive*)this` call?

Tags: c++, inheritance, this

Here is the sample code:

```
class B{
    A* get(){
        if(...) return ((D*)this)->get();
        else return NULL:
    }
}

class D : public B{
    A* a;
    A* get(){return a};
}
```

What will `this` call? `B::get()` or `D::get()`.

If `D::get()` will be called.

Then, if `de_func` is only defined in Derive, what will `((Derive*)this)->de_func()` call ?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: It was written by others, I just try to figure out it.@SanderDeDycker

Comment: tell those others that they've written something extremely ugly that should be replaced with something that actually makes sense. Or teach them about the [`virtual`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual) keyword.

Comment: A more complete [mcve] is needed. The answer depends a lot on how the instances of the objects are created (and referenced) - it could be UB or work pretty much as you may expect (a `virtual` method may be better though...).

Answer (score 2):

`D::get()` since you cast `this` to `D*`.

`this->get()` will call `B::get()` if you don't cast it.

Comment: But `this` is indeed Base*, if this calls D::get().Then,if` de_func` is only defined in Derive, what will`((Derive*)this)->de_func()` call?@Wiki Wang

Comment: It will still call Derive::de_func().

Comment: @YuanWen It's UB. Even with your current code it has been UB, since you're trying to call `D::get()` on `Base*`, and the function returns a member variable `D::a`.

Comment: @YuanWen If it is indeed a Base, as `Base *b = new Base; b->get();`, it will call Derive::de_func() with `this = b`, so if you do someting in Derive::de_func() that only works with Derive but Base, it will not work and most possibly will crash.

Comment: it can happens, more or less, what happens when you cast to a X pointer what is actually an Y pointer, with X,Y unrelated or not, and call a function on it. Prepare for fireworks (UB)